# Issue with importing products in magento

Tags: magento

I always have issues importing csv (products) into Magneto. No matter what I do I always get errors that don't make any sense and I can never import anything. I am on a mac and I've read that this can cause issues so I've been updating everything in google docs and then downloading it as a CSV. The current error I have is:

> "Can not find required columns: sku"

Which is a column in my CSV file.

Comment: pro tip: google magmi (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a Mac, you need to ensure that you are saving your CSV:

- In UTF-8 encoding
- as CSV (Windows) file type

If you want to deal with it manually, what you'll need to do is find and replace the line breaks in the file. From the command line:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file_excel_munged.csv >| fixed_file.csv
```

But just saving it was a Windows CSV/Excel file should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was able to export it as a"CSV (Windows) file type" but couldnt find how to also make sure it was in UTF-8 encoding. I'm still getting errors when trying to upload to magento..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this same issue today by saving as UTF-8 without BOM. By default I believe Excel will save with a BOM. Magento should really be smart enough to recognize the BOM imho.